# What will happen if we increment the function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers

Incrementing integer pointer will increase the address by size of integer. 
What will happen if we increment a function pointer?

Comment: unpredictable behaviour on using such a pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as with `void *` pointers and pointers to incomplete types, arithmetic is not allowed on pointers to functions.

For example, C99 §6.5.6 on Additive operators says:

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one
>   operand shall be a pointer to an object type and the other shall have
>   integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)

A function type is not an object type, so providing a pointer to a function as an operand of the `+` operator is a violation of this constraint.

---

As an extension to the C language, the GCC compiler allows arithmetic on pointers to functions (and pointers to `void`).  It implements this as if the pointed-to object had a size of 1.  Note that in standards-conforming modes it issues a warning for such code.

Comment: In this code, char (*ff)();int main(){printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof(ff), sizeof(ff+1), sizeof(ff+2));}, the output is 4 4 4. Why is it so?

Comment: @NeerajTuteja What compiler are you using?

Comment: @robmayoff GNU C Compiler 4.2.

Comment: @NeerajTuteja: A conforming compiler must at least issue a diagnostic message for that code.  After that, it has undefined behaviour, so if the compiler decides to produce an output then anything is allowed.  Note that with gcc if you give the `-pedantic` option then it produces a warning.

Comment: @NeerajTuteja GNU C has a documented extension of allowing arithmetic on `void` and function pointers, treating them as size 1.

Comment: @caf why doesn't `-Wall` include `-pedantic` ?

Comment: @SparKot: Broadly speaking, `-Wall` enables a set of warnings that most people will find broadly useful without giving too many false-positives.  The `-pedantic` warnings will be false positives on code that intends to use the gcc extensions.

Comment: @caf +1 for : GCC compiler allows arithmetic on pointers to functions (and pointers to void). It implements this as if the pointed-to object had a size of 1. Found that amusing, it's what I noticed while tryouts for the post!

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithematic is not allowed on void and function pointers.
However many of the compiler support pointer  arithematic through compiler extensions.
This is done by treating the size of a void or of a function as 1.

If you are using gcc then use the following flag to force the compiler to provide a diagnostic:

```
-Wpointer-arith
```